# .NET Aspire workload not showing in Visual Studio Installer

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-2022, .net-8.0, cloud-native

I am trying to install .Net Aspire, but it's now showing in the Visual Studio Installer, Ideally it should show like the below.

[image]

I am following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/aspire/setup-tooling?tabs=visual-studio#install-net-aspire) document. I have done the following steps as mentioned in the document.

1. Open the Visual Studio installer.
2. Select Modify next to Visual Studio 2022.
3. Select the ASP.NET and web development workload.

I have Visual Studio 17.8 installed, but in the document, it is mentioned that it requires version 17.9 or higher (Optional), But it is Optional.

Do I need to install the Visual Studio Preview version?

[image]

Comment: You are correct, You need to use preview 17.9 Refer this Blog- https://devclass.com/2023/11/14/microsoft-releases-net-8-with-preview-of-aspire-cloud-ready-stack-to-simplify-cloud-app-complexity/ -Full tooling is in the latest Visual Studio preview, 17.9 preview 1, which means Windows only for development, though Linux and Mac users can use it without some of the developer tools.

Comment: No, it doesn't mean Windows only. You can install and use Aspire from the command line on any OS. The linked docs clearly say that only 17.9 and higher support Aspire: `Visual Studio 2022 version 17.9 or higher`. VS Code has no issues because .... it doesn't have any specialized support.

Comment: Yes, Via .net cli > It can be installed, But your ask was specific to Visual Studio Installer and >net sdk Aspire was only visible in 17.9 preview version.

Comment: I cannot install it using cli: `Workload ID aspire is not recognized`

Answer (score 7):

Try reinstall NET8.SDK and run command:

```
dotnet workload install aspire
```

Comment: It doesn't work: `Workload ID aspire is not recognized`

Comment: you need to (re)install net8 sdk to get this working - https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/sdk-8.0.100-windows-x64-installer

Answer (score 4):

Even I was not able to Install **`.Net Aspire SDK`** in ***Visual Studio Community 2022 17.7.5***
[image]

According to this Blog- [Microsoft releases .NET 8 with preview of Aspire cloud-ready stack to 'simplify cloud app complexity' • DEVCLASS](https://devclass.com/2023/11/14/microsoft-releases-net-8-with-preview-of-aspire-cloud-ready-stack-to-simplify-cloud-app-complexity/) > ***The Full tooling of .Net Aspire is available in Visual Studio 2022 Preview - 17.9.0 Preview 1.0***

***I upgraded my existing Visual Studio 2022 Preview IDE to  17.9.0 Preview 1.0 and the .Net Aspire SDK (Preview) was visible and got installed successfully*** Refer below:-

[image]

Also, For **`.Net 8`** development,  I recommend using ***Visual Studio 2022 Preview*** version.

[image]

You can also install the Aspire SDK via .net CLI as an alternative as mentioned in the same MS Document.

```cs
dotnet workload install aspire
```

Comment: `I recommend using Visual Studio 2022 Preview version.` why? [17.8 fully supports .NET 8](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/visual-studio-17-8-now-available/). As for Aspire, the version requirements are in clearly shown in the official docs and blogs `Visual Studio 2022 version 17.9 or higher`

Comment: That's my personal recommendation for Creating .Net 8 API and apps, Yes, It will work with 17.8 version too. But the Aspire was only visible in 17.9 Preview version.

Comment: You wrote about .NET 8 in general, not Aspire. That's bad advice unless you have some *concrete* reason. Preview versions have bugs that will affect people

Comment: I personally did not see Aspire available in the Visual Studio version below 17.9, in the Visual Studio Installer. I'll create a Microsoft Document correction Github issue with the Microsoft Product team to get more insights on this.

Comment: The docs have no problem. [They clearly say it requires 17.9 or higher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/aspire/setup-tooling?tabs=dotnet-cli#install-net-aspire) `Visual Studio 2022 version 17.9 or higher (Optional)`

Comment: That's what My answer also suggests to upgrade the existing version to 17.9. I might have missed something, May I know what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255951/discussion-between-siddheshdesai-and-panagiotis-kanavos).

Comment: @SiddheshDesai Could you please check your answer, there is repeated content.

Comment: @VivekNuna I have edited my answer with proper content

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, what you need to do is go to Visual Studio Installer un-check in the Individual Components the .NET 8 ( might be shown as .NET Runtime) [image]
then hit the Modify button. This will completely uninstall .NET 8 SDK. Then all you have to do is download the .NET 8 SDK msi (installer), install it and then reopen a Windows terminal session. Now you can run `dotnet workload update` and then `dotnet workload install aspire`

[image]